# Customize colors in Python by Hue & category

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, color-palette

I have a dataframe with two categories: female and male, and 2 years. What I want is to have in the same plot both categories but specific colors by plot (it could be barplot or boxplot).

My code is:

```
test =pd.DataFrame([[2021, 'female', 3], [2021, 'male', 1], [2021, 'female', 6],
                    [2021, 'female', 3], [2021, 'male', 4], [2021, 'female', 10],
                    [2020, 'female', 2], [2020, 'male', 9], [2020, 'male', 7],
                    [2020, 'female', 1], [2020, 'male', 5], [2020, 'male', 8]
                   ], columns=['Year', 'category', 'value'])

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
g = sns.boxplot(y='value', x='category', data=test, hue='Year')
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xmajorticklabels(), fontsize = 12)
```

And mi current output is:

[image: This is the current output]

What I expect to have is something like this:

[image]

Change the libraries is not a problem, if I can get a automatic way to have this plot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a library that does this kind of coloring out-of-the-box.  With a seaborn `boxplot`, you could iterate through the generated boxes and assign individual colors and transparencies. A custom legend could show the transparency via shades of grey:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame([[2021, 'female', 3], [2021, 'male', 1], [2021, 'female', 6],
                     [2021, 'female', 3], [2021, 'male', 4], [2021, 'female', 10],
                     [2020, 'female', 2], [2020, 'male', 9], [2020, 'male', 7],
                     [2020, 'female', 1], [2020, 'male', 5], [2020, 'male', 8]
                     ], columns=['Year', 'category', 'value'])

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.boxplot(y='value', x='category', data=test, hue='Year')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)

hue_values = np.sort(test['Year'].unique())
num_hue_values = len(hue_values)
colors = ['crimson', 'dodgerblue']
min_alpha = 0.3
max_alpha = 0.6
alphas = np.linspace(min_alpha, max_alpha, num_hue_values)
for i, box in enumerate(ax.artists):
    box.set_facecolor(colors[i // num_hue_values])
    box.set_alpha(alphas[i % num_hue_values])
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, facecolor='black', edgecolor='black', alpha=alpha, label=label)
           for alpha, label in zip(alphas, hue_values)]
ax.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot with hue by alpha]

Here is another example with more hue categories:

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.boxplot(y='total_bill', x='sex', data=tips, hue='day')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)

hue_values = tips['day'].cat.categories
num_hue_values = len(hue_values)
colors = ['lime', 'purple']
min_alpha = 0.3
max_alpha = 0.6
alphas = np.linspace(min_alpha, max_alpha, num_hue_values)
for i, box in enumerate(ax.artists):
    box.set_facecolor(colors[i // num_hue_values])
    box.set_alpha(alphas[i % num_hue_values])
handles = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, facecolor='black', edgecolor='black', alpha=alpha, label=label)
           for alpha, label in zip(alphas, hue_values)]
ax.legend(handles=handles)
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot from tips dataset, alpha for hue]